# in xAct, how to set the components of a tensor to be zero

Tags: xact

OBASuppose there is a vector $A^{a}$ appears in the result in different component form like $A^{\mu},A^{\nu},A^{\alpha}...$,
I want all of them to be zero because the components of the tensor are zero, what method can I use?

Answer (score 2):

You have two main ways of doing this:

```
expr /. A[_] -> 0
```

or

```
expr /. A -> Zero
```

where Zero is a xTensor object that returns 0 for any input indices.